# Avoid QProcess being killed (QProcess: Destroyed while process is still running)

Tags: java, c++, qt, cmd, qprocess

I tried to run this code:

```
QProcess process;
process.setWorkingDirectory("D:\\Programs\\Qt\\Units\\MyJavaProjects\\StackExp\\target");
process.setProgram("java.exe");
process.setArguments({"-jar","StackExp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"});
process.start();
```

and cmd won't open, and doesn't execute. It just shows this message:

```
QProcess: Destroyed while process ("java.exe") is still running
```

Please, who knows what's wrong? And how can I run my .jar file using cmd in QProcess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably calling the [destructor of `QProcess`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#dtor.QProcess) before it is finished, which kills the process as mentioned in the docs. Note that the destructor is called when `process` goes out of scope.

Different solutions exists:

1. Wait for process to finish: [`waitForFinished`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#waitForFinished)

   ```
   process.waitForFinished (-1); // -1 = no time out
   ```
2. Construct `QProcess` on the stack

   ```
   QProcess *process = new QProcess();
   ...
   ```

   Note that you should destruct the process after it is finished to avoid a memory leak. Specifying a [`parent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#QProcess) during construction may be useful to automatically manage the lifetime of `QProcess`.
3. Start the process in detached mode: [`startDetached`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached)

   ```
   ...
   process.startDetached ();
   ```

   > If the calling process exits, the detached process will continue to run unaffected.

   One could also use the static overload of [`QProcess::startDetached`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached-1).